# Symfony2 - Embedded form logic

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've been breaking my head over this issue. First of all, I'll explain the database structure of the application I'm creating. We're talking about a ebay-ish website (where you can buy/sell secondhand products).

[image: DB model]

As you can see, each category can have specific metafield (for example, if you're selling a car, you can specify color, brand, ...). Metafields are created in the backoffice by administrators. metafield_types are 'number, text, checkboxes, radiobuttons'.

In the Metadata table, you can find the actual data to these metafields for each product. (for example, color of car X has a value 'blue').

The issue I'm having is situated in the 'Add product' page, as I want to create a form that contains all product columns, as well as the metadata columns. I created following form type for my product:

```
<?php

namespace Scouter\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProductType extends AbstractType {

    protected $em;

    function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Title', 'text', array(
                'required'       => true,
            ))
            ->add('description', 'textarea')
            ->add('condition', 'choice', [
                'choices'   => array(
                    'new'   => 'Nieuw',
                    'used' => 'Gebruikt',
                ),
                'multiple'  => false,
                'expanded' => false,
            ])
            ->add('price', 'money')
            ->add('city', 'text')
            ->add('media', 'hidden')
            ->add('add', 'submit')
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $form->add('category', 'entity', array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'class' => 'ScouterBundle:Category',
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'empty_value' => 'Kies een categorie',
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'expanded' => false,
                    ));

                $data = $event->getData();

                $category = $data->getCategory();
                $metafields = null === $category ? array() : $category->getMetafields();

                $form->add('metadata', 'collection', array('type' => new MetadataType()));
            }
        );
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Scouter\ScouterBundle\Entity\Product'
        ));
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return "productType";
    }

}
```

I'm stuck at the last line of my form event.. This is what needs to happen: Foreach Metafield, a textfield/checkboxes/radiobuttons needs to be added to the form with a label that is specified in the Metafield. I should be able to pass the Metafield to the Metadata Type, in order to determine which field type should be used, I just don't see how...

Enlighten me, please!

Comment: Probably need to use a dynamic form: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a class Metadata for the table "metadata". Metadata must have a method "getMetadataTypes($productId, $metaField)" or "getMetadataTypeArray($productId, $metaFieldArray)". The method getMetadataTypeArray reads the database table "metadata" and returns the needed array of the field type, name and options, and the resulting array of the meta values stored for the meta field id "metafield_id" and the product id "product_id".

```
$metafieldArray = null === $category ? array() : $category->getMetafields('');
$metadata = new Metadata();
$productId = ...; // read in the product id
$metadataTypeArray = $metadata->getMetadataTypeArray($productId, $metafieldArray);
$form->add('metadata', 'collection', $metadataTypeArray);
```

This is not a really working PHP code to be used. It should only help you to find the right direction to solve it.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple 'collections' of the same property, in this case metadata?

Comment: You are probably right.
I have modified it in the way that the whole $metadataTypeArray is added. This array must be formed of the right syntax which is needed for the Symfony Form.